# convert double[] into Number[] in android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I wish to draw a chart by using androidplot.jar lib in android. How can I convert double array into Number array in java?

```
XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(number1),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");
```

In above case: number1 is a Number[] but if it is a double[] or an ArrayList, what can o do?

Answer (score 2):

If you already use Guava, you can use:

```
List<Double> list = Doubles.asList(number1);
```

Otherwise, you need to loop manually:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double> (number1.length);
for (double d : number1) list.add(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a library this is the fastest way from `double[]` to `Number[]`:

```
double[] doubles = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
Number[] numbers = new Number[doubles.length];
for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
  numbers[i] = doubles[i];
}
```

(This is what Gopal Rao wrote but then deleted?)

That's what you asked. But your API call needs a `List<Number>` right? If you had a `List` already, you'd be done. If you have `double[]`, then it's assylias's answer:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>(doubles.length);
for (double d : doubles) {
  numbers.add(d);
}
```

Comment: the [API](http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.6.0/com/androidplot/xy/SimpleXYSeries.html#SimpleXYSeries(java.util.List,%20com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat,%20java.lang.String)) seems to expect a `List<? extends Number>` so a `List<Double>` should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Sean Owen, it works fine for me! It is basic but i don't think.